# esptool.py PermissionError while configuring serial port

Tags: port, serial-port, com, configure

esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM11

> A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)Error while setting serial port parameters: 115,200 N 8 1

Trying to upload the code to the ESP8266

Comment: You do not have permission to access the serial port.  On a debian based linux distribution (including ubuntu) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm actually using Windows, not a Debian-based Linux distribution. Do you have any instructions for accessing the serial port on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I got a new batch of NodeMCU's and was not able to connect and upload code from Arduino IDE. My CH341 driver in windows 11 was automatically updated recently!. i found a driver from 2019 https://electropeak.com/learn/download/ch341ser-zip/. and updated my driver to this version by "Update Driver" from the downloaded unzipped file. Wupti everything started to work after a reboot of my PC. Thanks for your help - It saved me many hours :-) Best Regards Erling Hviid

Comment: I did a driver update using the setup.exe file in the downloaded zip file. I then was prompted to restart Windows. After doing so, I was able to successfully connect to my esp8266 and upload program. Funny thing is that it appears to be the same driver version, 3.5.2019.1, driver date 1/30/2019 so I'm not sure what the deal was. However it's working now.

Comment: After trying it out, it initially seemed to be working. However, I soon realized that I couldn't type using my keyboard anymore. None of the words were registering as input; instead, they were causing other applications to open. So, I uninstalled the application, which fixed the keyboard issue. Unfortunately, the problem still persisted with Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for almost 5 days now.
Most of the suggestions given online say that the com port is in use. I checked everything including process manager and nothing was using the port.

I came across a solution on [this site](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-serialutil-serialexception-cannot-configure-port-something-went-wrong-original-message-permissionerror-13-a-device-attached-to-the-system/1123035/3). It seems its a new driver issue.

I downloaded the driver, link given on a comment by maf, and tried to install, it failed. So I switched off the internet to try again. I first hit the uninstall option and later did the install. It worked from that point onwards.
I have reconnected the internet and so far it has not auto updated the driver.
My serial monitor works now.

[link of driver given by maf](https://web.archive.org/web/20211129002033/http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH341SER_EXE.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate your expertise and guidance. I will review your suggestions and implement them as soon as possible. Thanks again for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused by a new CH340 driver that was automatically upgraded a few days ago. To roll-back the upgrade go to windows device manager, under COM ports go to properties of the CH340 driver, and on the driver tab chose option to revert to the previous version of the driver. Now esptool should work again.

Comment: Great, thank you for sharing your experience and the solution you found! I will try reverting to the previous version of the CH340 driver as you suggested and see if it resolves the issue with esptool. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Can somebody please add the exact version numbers of the drivers that work and don't work?